# How to pick last column from data and print sum of it?

Tags: perl

trying with:

```
my @header = split(/\,/,$recIn,-1);
print "Header Feed Date: $header[2]\n";
chop($header[2]);
```

Comment: What is your input here and what does your output need to be?

Comment: Input is data file. (the above data file) that needs to be validated with the perl script.

example, perl validation_script.pl input_data_file

Comment: (1) "_the above data file_" --- But that already has the line asked about? (2) "_needs to be validated_" -- so the purpose is to check that line? // Then update the question to state that.  Also, I see no relation between the code you show ("_trying with_") and what you are saying?

Comment: That final is supposed to be printed. Data file contains only data records.
Or, lets leave above validation. How to take count of all individual records from file print it along with Aggregate of last column?

Comment: So your input file is the header line and then the three lines of records, and that line with `FINAL...` is what you want printed?

Comment: Yes!
Able to get number of lines using 
'perl -ne 'if (eof) {printf "%6d %s\n",$.,$ARGV;close @ARGV}' check.dat

---check.dat is the input file here.
But stuck at navigating to last column and print sum of all 3 records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $tot = 0;

my $header = <>; 

while (<>) { 
    $tot += (split /,/)[-1];    
}

say join ',', 'FINAL', $.-1, $tot;
```

The [`<>` operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#I/O-Operators) reads lines of files submitted at command-line at invocation. The [`$.` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#$.) is the current line number of the last-used filehandle.

Formatting of numbers (and the number of their decimal places) is nicely down with `printf`.

---

The above processes data from a file.  However, the last line, with `FINAL...`, that is shown in the question is indeed the last line of the input file, which need be checked.  Then that also shouldn't be processed so we need to add a check

```
while (<>) { 
    if (/^\s*FINAL/) { 
        my @fields = split /,/;
        if ($.-1 != $fields[1] or $tot != $fields[-1]) {
            warn "Wrong FINAL line: $_";
        }
        last;
    }

    $tot += (split /,/)[-1];    
}
```

But then we process that line multiple (three) times.  It is nicer, and also certainly more amenable to checking input data, to first `split` each line into an array and use the ready array

```
while (<>) {
    my @fields = split /,/;

   # Is this the last line, with a summary to be checked?
    if ($fields[0] eq 'FINAL') {
        if ($.-1 != $fields[1] or $tot != $fields[-1]) {
            warn "Wrong FINAL line: $_";
        }
        last;
    }

    # Validate input if/as needed

    $tot += $fields[-1];
}
```

This added array construction reflects visibly (and negatively) on the efficiency only if the file is rather large, or many such files are processed. But if input data indeed need be checked for format, validity, or pre-processed in any way, then of course there is no choice.  (In very short files this may be more efficient but one would be hard pressed to detect that since it's about only one line.)

Another option, if the file isn't too large, is to read all lines into an array first, peel off the unneeded first line (header) and the last summary line, and process the rest

```
my @lines = <>;
chomp @lines;

my $header = shift @lines;

my $final = pop @lines;

foreach my $line (@lines) { 
    # or split into an array for checking of various fields etc
    $tot += (split /,/, $line)[-1];
}
say join ',', 'FINAL', scalar @lines, $tot;

CHECK_FINAL_LINE: { 
    my @fields = split /,/, $final;
    if ( $fields[1] != @lines or $fields[-1] != $tot ) { 
        warn "FINAL summary line wrong: $final";
    }
};
```

Now we avoid checking each and every line for whether it is the last.

The number of data lines is the length of the array `@lines`, produced when `@lines` array is used in scalar [context](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#Context), like in the `if` in the last block. I put the check in a block so to avoid introducing a `@fields` array for the rest of the program (this way it's scoped to that block only), and I name the block `CHECK_FINAL_LINE` for convenience/clarity. The block isn't necessary.

In the line where the calculated final is printed though we have a list context, imposed by `print` (and so by `say`), and we actually need an explicit `scalar`.

Comment: But as per this, sum value is getting printed wrongly. It is printing as 927.12
Seems like it is getting doubled.

Comment: @Karuna This is what it's printing: `FINAL,3,463.56` (with the input file exactly as you show in the question).  How do you run it -- as `progname input-file-name`? (or `perl progname input-file-name`) Is the input file you use the same as you show in the question?

Comment: @Karuna You see what it does, yes?  First it throws away (reads) the header line. Then, it goes through lines and it `split`'s each line by comma and takes the last element, and adds that to `$tot`.  Once for each line.  So it can't really be wrong.

Comment: Im sorry, My bad. I've changed the functionality for testing.
This have worked. Will alter with more records and develop test cases for null handling.

Thanks a lot. A lot for help.

Comment: @Karuna Most welcome.  Let me know if more questions come up

Comment: Really thanks a lot, just started learning scripting. Getting stuck with implementation sometime. Need some guidance, will let you know. Thanks much for help.

Comment: @Karuna The `$.` is a variable for which I link to documentation so please look it up -- it's the line number that's being read (when `<>` reads the fifth line `$.` is equal to 5, etc), in short.  So after the whole file has been read it is the number of lines in the file.  But, you need to subtract the header line, so `$. - 1`.

Comment: "_just started learning scripting_" -- enjoy it :)

Comment: @Karuna Ah, OK -- so you _do_ have that last line and need to check it.  I am adding that to the answer...

Comment: @Karuna  Edited to add that, and quite a bit once I was at it... Please check carefully as I didn't get to do that